# errorPlacement for Radio button with ul and li for jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, validation, radio-button, html-lists, errorplacement

I am trying to display the error message for a group of radio buttons in a div with class "Errors". All input element's error messages display on the correct place except for this group of radio buttons.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="radio"  value="organic1" name="payment" />Organic1</li>
    <li><input type="radio"  value="organic2" name="payment" />Organic2</li>
    <li><input type="radio"  value="organic3" name="payment" />Organic3</li>
    <li><input type="radio"  value="organic4" name="payment" />Organic4</li>
    <li><input type="radio"  value="organic5" name="payment" />Organic5</li>
    <li><input type="radio"  value="organic6" name="payment" />Organic6</li>
</ul>
<br style="clear:both;">
<div class="Errors"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#form").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {  
        if (element.is(":radio")) {
            error.insertAfter(element.closest('ul.radio'));
            error.addClass('.Errors');

            // Also, I have tried all this but no use
            //error.appendTo(element.closest('ul.radio').find('div.Errors'));
            //$(element).closest('li').next().find('div.Errors').html(error);
            //error.appendTo(element.parent().find('div.Errors'));
        }
    }
}
```

Please Advice,

Comment: What is the validation script you are using ?

Comment: http://www.jqueryvalidation.org

Comment: Where is the code for all the other input elements, which seem to be working?

Answer (score 0):

To output the error in the `.Errors` element,
I recommend using [`errorLabelContainer`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorlabelcontainer):

> Hide and show this container when validating.
>
> Example: All error labels are displayed inside an unordered list with the ID "messageBox", as specified by the selector passed as errorContainer option. All error elements are wrapped inside a li element, to create a list of messages.
>
> ```
> $("#myform").validate({
>   errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
>   wrapper: "li",
>   submitHandler: function() { alert("Submitted!") }
> });
> ```

Here's a demonstration:

```js
$("#form").validate({
  messages: {
    stuff: {
      required: "Please enter some stuff."
    },
    payment: {
      required: "Please select a payment."
    }
  },
  rules: {
    payment: "required",
    stuff: "required"
  },
  errorContainer: ".Errors",
  errorLabelContainer: ".Errors ul",
  wrapper: "li"
});
```

```css
#errors {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}

label.error {
  display: block;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
  <ul>
    <li><input type="text" name="stuff"></li>
    <li><input type="radio" value="organic1" name="payment" />Organic1</li>
    <li><input type="radio" value="organic2" name="payment" />Organic2</li>
    <li><input type="radio" value="organic3" name="payment" />Organic3</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<div class="Errors">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

---

### EDIT

With your current method, use [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$('.Errors').append(error);
```

Or [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/):

```
error.appendTo($('.Errors'));
```

Or to insert errors after another element, use [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$('#form').after(error);
```

Or [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/):

```
error.insertAfter($('#form'));
```